# I have created hitboxes for my flappy dragon but the hitboxes are either not colliding or doesn't produce an output. How do i fix that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-clock, pygame-tick

I'm trying to make a flappybird game for my Python programming class and I used cues like drag.hit() that causes them to print("hit") everytime the hitboxes supposedly collides. However, the collision of dragon and stumpy hitbox are not working and I cant seem to get it to work.

Heres my code:

```
    pygame.init()

class player(object):   **class for dragon**
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 5, self.y +3, 67, 65)

 def draw(self,win):     **drawing of hitbox for dragon**
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 5, self.y +3, 67, 65)     
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)

    def hit(self):        **During collision of hitbox, print hit**
        print("hit")


class stumpy(object):    **class for obstacle 1**
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 8, self.y+10, self.width - 18, self.height-15)


    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.walkLeft[self.count//3], (75, 200)), (self.x, self.y))      #fx to scale up or down object. transform, dimension, placement
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 2)  #arguments - window, colour, dimension, thickness
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 8, self.y+10, self.width - 18, self.height-15) #x-start, y-start, length, breath

class stumper(object):      **class for obstacle 2**
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):

        self.hitbox = (self.x + 8, self.y+10, self.width - 18, self.height-20)     


    def draw(self,win):
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 8, self.y+10, self.width - 18, self.height-20)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox, 2)
        win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(self.walkLeft[self.count//1], (75,200)), (self.x,self.y))


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (bgX,0))  # This will draw our background image at (0,0)
    win.blit(bg, (bgX2,0))  # This will draw our background image at (1024,0)
    drag.draw(win)

    for obstacle in obstacles:
        obstacle.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()

speed = 30             **assign variable for fps**
drag = player(95, 396//2, 75, 73)       #class for dragon, unnecessary
stump = stumpy(810, 310, 75, 200)     #class for stump, unnecessary
Istump = stumper(810, -20, 75, 200)


obstacles= []
#main loop
run = True
while run:
    redrawGameWindow()
    pygame.time.delay(25)

    for obstacle in obstacles:

        if drag.hitbox[1] < Istump.hitbox[1] + Istump.hitbox[3] and drag.hitbox[1] + drag.hitbox[3] > stump.hitbox[1]:      #must create player instance for this to work so using class is useless
            if drag.hitbox[0] + drag.hitbox[2] > Istump.hitbox[0] and drag.hitbox[0] < Istump.hitbox[0] + Istump.hitbox[2]:
                 if drag.hitbox[0] + drag.hitbox[2] > stump.hitbox[0] and drag.hitbox[0] < stump.hitbox[0] + stump.hitbox[2]:
                     drag.hit()
                     obstacles.append(stumpy(250, 250, 100, 100))



    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the hitboxesm, and find collision by [.colliderect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your player class, use pygame rect for your hitbox:

```
self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 5, self.y +3, 67, 65)
```

Then do the same for your objects so that both player and obstacles are pygame.Rect objects. To detect whether the player is in an obstacle you then simply use:

```
if player.hitbox.colliderect(obstacle.hitbox):
    print('hit')
```